# Comparing two tables and deleting stale data

Tags: sql, compare, sql-delete, records

I'm trying to delete stale records in a table based on another table.  Our issue is that courses were given to students in two different buildings in Table_A.  We need to compare `Table_A` to `Table_B`, based on Student_ID and Building.  If the student's `Table_B` Building does not match `Table_A`, delete record that do not have the same building, but keep the ones that are in the same building.

`Table_A` contains student schedules:

- SCHOOL_YEAR
- STUDENT_ID
- BUILDING
- COURSE

`Table_B` contains the students registration:

- STUDENT_ID
- BUILDING

Here is what I've come up with:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A
WHERE exists 
(SELECT Table_B.STUDENT_ID, Table_B.BUILDING, TABLE_A.BUILDING 
FROM TABLE_B
INNER JOIN TABLE_A ON Table_B.STUDENT_ID = Table_A.STUDENT_ID 
AND Table_B.BUILDING <> Table_A.BUILDING
AND Table_A.SCHOOL_YEAR = 2015)
```

Comment: Its not clear what part of your current query doesnt work.  Perhaps some sample data or a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @paqogomez, the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Many databases have different syntaxes for deleting the contents of one table based on values from another. Which database are you running? This will help get better answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A
WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (SELECT a.STUDENT_ID
                     FROM TABLE_B b
                     JOIN TABLE_A a ON (a.STUDENT_ID = b.STUDENT_ID)
                     WHERE a.BUILDING <> b.BUILDING
                       AND a.SCHOOL_YEAR = 2015)
```

Comment: I tried the same script and it was giving me the same results.  It was deleting all records.  I ended up creating a temp table with only the data I wanted and found the records that didn't exist in the temp table.  Thanks everyone for your input.